# Update with regexp_replace replaces match with literal regex pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace, mariadb

I am trying to update a column in MariaDB using regexp_replace. I've tested this out in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f7361077ddd0397cdd72232546a53b8) and it works just fine, however when I update and export the table, it seems that the match is replaced by the literal regex pattern - href="#h_$1" .

This is my query:

```
UPDATE blog_posts
SET blog_content = regexp_replace(blog_content, 'href="[^#"]+#h_(.+)"', 'href="#h_$1"');
```

Did anyone encounter this before and if yes how can I solve it?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support back-references in `regexp_replace()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **\\1** to select the pattern. try:

```
UPDATE blog_posts
SET blog_content = regexp_replace(blog_content, 'href="[^#"]+#h_(.+)"', 'href="#h_\\1"');
```

see manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/